# @Component annotation to be used with qualifier

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have a single class with 
`@Component` annotation

```
@Component
public class MyClass {}
```

Now I wanna use it with two different scopes: `prototype` and `singleton` without defining it in configuration. 
Is that possible?

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind using instance as singleton and prototype in different case?

Comment: You can do it, if you use an @Bean annotated method to create the bean (then you can write two methods with different scopes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There should never be a use case for having the same bean in two different scopes. It's a huge architectural smell and you should probably redesign your application.
2. That said, perhaps you mean you need to inject a prototype-scoped bean into a singleton bean? That's a common use case and the implications are adressed in these manual sections:

   - [Singleton beans with prototype-bean dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction)
   - [Scoped beans as dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection)
3. But if you do insist to have the same bean in two different scopes, that can be achieved by using `@Bean` methods:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class MyConfig{
       @Bean public MyClass singletonScope(){ return new MyClass(); }
       @Bean @Scope("prototype") public MyClass prototypeScope(){ return new MyClass(); }
   }
   ```

Comment: Was just curious to know, not gonna use it. Thanks